# Using the strategy pattern to send different message

Tags: java, design-patterns

I have a basic class that takes a socket connection and sends different messages depending on which of the overloaded methods are called

```
public void send(byte[] message) {...}
public void send(String message) {...}
...
```

Each method parameter eventually gets converted to a byte array to be sent over the socket depending on the protocol. I was looking into the strategy pattern and it seems like it could be applicable. Instead of having one class with a number of overloaded methods, I could have different send strategies. The only question I have is how do I account for the different message parameter types? Or if there is a better way that I am missing, please let me know.

Comment: I think this is not purpose of Strategy pattern. Strategy pattern is applicable when you have multiple instances of one class which you need to behave differently.

Comment: How the `send(...)` methods are called? Where and how is done the choice?

Comment: It seems to me that an overloaded send() is the easiest to use for the client code. The send methods can of course use various patterns/classes to actually convert the parameter to the required byte array to send out.

Comment: Does the message content passed to the send method contain the protocol information as well? If yes, does the logic for sending a message using different protocols require the use of different API's/libraries?

Comment: @bot no, based on the message type, I would know which protocol to use when sending over the socket.

Comment: @yellavon By message type, do you mean the type of parameter passed to the send method (i.e String, bute []array, Image, etc) ? Also, what about my second question about the use of different API? Can two messages that are of the same type be sent using different protocols? For instance, can a byte[] data be sent over HTTP and also over SOAP?

Comment: @bot yes, depending on the parameter type. For your second question, no, two message of the same type will never be sent with different protocols.

Comment: @yellavon That means you are binding the protocol to a particular type in Java. This is kind of counter-productive. On one hand, you want to use the Strategy pattern to decide how a message gets sent over the wire. On the other hand, which message gets sent over the wire using what strategy is tightly coupled to a type. The code that creates the messages should not know what protocol they are going to be sent over. All the messages should be of the same type. Do you agree?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about using generics coupled to a classic Strategy pattern design:

```
//Strategy Contract
public interface SendStrategy<F>{
    public void send(F data);
}

public class StringSender implements SendStrategy<String>{
    public void send(String data){};
}

public class ByteArraySender implements SendStrategy<byte[]>{
    public void send(byte[] data){};
}
```

Comment: What happens when byte[] needs to be sent over HTTP as well as SOAP?

Comment: protocol related (meta-)data should probably handled at a higher level (prior to the conversion into bytes).

Comment: So the higher level needs to know what protocol will be used to send the data. Don't you think this is counter-productive? If the higher layer knows what protocol will be used to send the data, why create a false abstraction at the lower layer?

Comment: The higher level is actually an implementation of the SendStrategy contract, that will call the 'native' byte implementation after handling any necessary meta data.

Comment: The lower layer decides how to send the data using the type of message. If the higher layer does not know what protocol will be used to send the data, how will it know what type of message to create? If the higher layer already knows what protocol will be used to send the data, then the lower layer being designed not to know is pointless right?

Answer (score 0):

You can have a Processor interface with send(Object obj) method.

Then you can have implementations like StringProcessor, ByteArrayProcessor etc which handles the appropriate operation.

Based on the type of message, the invoker has to instantiate a proper Processor type.

Comment: okay, then everyone who uses such processor should know which particular type of `obj` it accepts--which is much more confusing than multiple overloaded methods.

Answer (score 0):

Well, quoting [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern), "the strategy pattern [...] is a software design pattern that enables an algorithm's behavior to be selected at runtime."

Here, you want your behavior to be selected at compile time, as it depends on the type of the message to send.

So, to simplify things, the Strategy DP is not applicable here.

Actually, things are a bit more complex. You could actually write a `public void send(Object message)` that will then use reflection to determine the correct strategy by derivating it from the object class name (taken here as a class such as e.g. `myprogram.sendmessage.strategies.Integer`) -- beware template classes ; and then use this strategy to send the message.

However, you lose any compile-time check that a message of such a type can actually be sent.

The question now is : is it really worth all this trouble just to use a DP that's not suited for the application ?

Anyway, there could be a better way to go, depending on whether your protocol is already rigid. You could just implement a `send(Serializable o)` function and let Java do the magic of serializing the object `o` in and out of the stream.

Comment: There is one very big problem with `Object` as a parameter: it is confusing

Comment: *use reflection to determine the correct strategy by derivating it from the object class name*--I believe `instanceof` is enough

Comment: Well, here the objective would be that the user of the `send` method could add types that can be sent without modifying the sending method itself. So using `instanceof` would reduce the number of possible classes to a limited number, just like overloading, and indeed make this design completely pointless, while on certain edge cases you could possibly want to use such a complicated concept.

Comment: *using instanceof would reduce the number of possible classes*-- you can always scan starting from least common classes to most common

Comment: Well... This does not change the fact that without changing the `send` method you cannot add support for a new type, does it ? You will always have a finite number of `instanceof` clauses in your `send` method, number that cannot be increased without modifying the method's code. Or do I misunderstand you ?